# libvlc_new (0, NULL); segmentation fault

Tags: qt-creator, libvlc

I have a problem when I use this line :

```
   vlcInstance = libvlc_new(0, NULL);
```

*vlcInstance* is declare in my header:

```
  libvlc_media_player_t *vlcPlayer;
```

I am using Qt 5.0.1 and I have this error:

```
The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the Operating System.

Signal name : SIGSEGV Signal meaning : Segmentation fault
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Latest Qt Creator version is currently 2.8.0, do you mean Qt version? Can you precise the version number (5.x.x)? Did you try with Qt 4.8?

Comment: I had Qt Creator 5.1 I will try with 4.8 thank you for your answer :)

Comment: 5.0.1 sorry for my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Qt Creator 2.7.2 with QT 5.1.0 on 64-bit Kubuntu 13.04. I'm also using vlc-2.2.0-git.

I created a new QT project.

I added this to the new project file (change your vlc paths as needed):

```
INCLUDEPATH += /home/linux/vlc/install/include
LIBS += -L"/home/linux/vlc/install/lib" -lvlc
```

bare-bones main.cpp (including your code that apparently segfaults):

```
#include <QtDebug>

#include "vlc/libvlc.h"
#include "vlc/libvlc_media.h"
#include "vlc/libvlc_media_player.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    qDebug() << "Starting...";

    libvlc_instance_t* p_instance = libvlc_new(0, NULL);
    qDebug() << "p_instance" << p_instance;

    if (p_instance) {
        libvlc_media_player_t *p_media_player = libvlc_media_player_new(p_instance);
        qDebug() << "p_media_player" << p_media_player;

        if (p_media_player) {
            libvlc_media_player_release(p_media_player);
        }

        libvlc_free(p_instance);
    }

    qDebug() << "Exit normally";
}
```

This runs just fine for me, no segfault:

```
Starting... 
p_instance 0x19140f0 
p_media_player 0x19da6d8 
Exit normally
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem on Windows with a simple program linked against prebuilt static lib from the VLC distribution. The solution was just to copy the `.dll` files and the `plugins` folder from the VLC distribution root to application folder.

Comment: I discovered - on Wndows,  using Visual Studio - that the same worked for me just now (i.e., copy the root folder of VLC player's installation, in to your debug/release folder of your VC++ project.).  This root folder has all the folder structures and config files necessary in order for libVLC to Initialise.