# How to fix crashing C in Windows 8.1?

Tags: c, windows, gcc, mingw, vlc

I'm using Code Blocks with MinGW Gcc. Compile build works fine but it crashes when I execute it to run:

[image]

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vlc/vlc.h>
#include <vlc/libvlc.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    libvlc_instance_t *vlc;
    vlc = libvlc_new (0, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Build log:

```
-------------- Clean: Debug in rtsp (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Cleaned "rtsp - Debug"

-------------- Build: Debug in rtsp (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -g -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\sdk\include" -c C:\Users\sunuser\Desktop\c\rtsp\main.c -o obj\Debug\main.o
C:\Users\sunuser\Desktop\c\rtsp\main.c: In function 'main':
C:\Users\sunuser\Desktop\c\rtsp\main.c:8:24: warning: variable 'vlc' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
mingw32-g++.exe -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\sdk\lib" -o bin\Debug\rtsp.exe obj\Debug\main.o  -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\sdk\include"  "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\sdk\lib\vlc.lib" "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\sdk\lib\vlccore.lib" "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\sdk\lib\libvlc.lib"
Output file is bin\Debug\rtsp.exe with size 29.64 KB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
0 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
```

Why is this happening?

How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17854517/2173917) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22965654/2173917) can help?

Comment: On Linux Always Works. My problem is on Windows 8.1 or 7 libvlc is never working with C

Comment: @YumYumYum have you included the .dll files needed?